# SQL Server : left outer join on multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, left-join, outer-join

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
    post_id, title, publish
FROM
    TABLE_A
    FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON ( TABLE_A.post_id = TABLE_B.post_id )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C ON ( TABLE_B.publish = TABLE_C.publish )
```

Output:

```
post_id | title   | publish
P000001   TitleA    202308
P000002   TitleB    202308
P000003   TitleC    202308
P000004   TitleD    202308
```

Then I want to display more column company_id in 2 tables TABLE_A and TABLE_D, so I did the following:

```
SELECT
    post_id, title, publish, company_id
FROM
    TABLE_A
    FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON ( TABLE_A.post_id = TABLE_B.post_id )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C ON ( TABLE_B.publish = TABLE_C.publish )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_D ON ( TABLE_A.company_id = TABLE_D.company_id )
```

Output:

```
post_id | title   | publish | company_id
P000001   TitleA    202308    111
P000001   TitleA    202308    111
P000002   TitleB    202308    222
P000002   TitleB    202308    222
P000002   TitleB    202308    222
P000003   TitleC    202308    333
P000003   TitleC    202308    333
P000003   TitleC    202308    333
P000003   TitleC    202308    333
P000004   TitleD    202308    444
```

Since the output was the same, I used `SELECT DISTINCT` and the result was as expected.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT post_id, title, publish, company_id
FROM
    TABLE_A
    FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON ( TABLE_A.post_id = TABLE_B.post_id )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_C ON ( TABLE_B.publish = TABLE_C.publish )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_D ON ( TABLE_A.company_id = TABLE_D.company_id )
```

Output:

```
post_id | title   | publish | company_id
P000001   TitleA    202308    111
P000002   TitleB    202308    222
P000003   TitleC    202308    333
P000004   TitleD    202308    444
```

What is a way to not use `SELECT DISTINCT`
but use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or something like that and still get the expected result?

Comment: 1) Use Group by instead of distinct 2) Ask yourself why title and post_Id get duplicated.  Are there duplicate records in the table D or are you missing join critiera which would eliminate the duplicates?  Focus on one record at a time and find out what is causing the duplication.  My guess is you eihter have duplicates in some tables or your missing join critiera to preven tthe duplication; or there are other fields in the talbe which make it unique and thus duplication occurs in which case a group by or distinct would be needed.

Comment: Maybe  Table_ D is an Author table, and if `TitleA` has 2 authors, `TitleC` has 4 authors, then for sure your rows will get duplicated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `DISTINCT`, you should  be working out why there is a join issue happening. Otherwise your query does extra working joining redundant records, and extra work `distinct` ing then out again. Besides it's important to understand properly how joins work

Comment: why are you using `full outer join`? is there a real reason or is this "just in case"? legitimate uses of full outer joins are relatively rare - try your query with an inner join instead. **nb** full outer joins are not great for performance, use only when absolutely necessary.

Comment: To definitively answer this question we would need to have DDL & data for each table - only then would we know why you are getting `unwanted repetition` (which isn't actual evidence of duplication) in the result. Keep in mind that joins MULTIPLY the rows - so to avoid that multiplication effect you need one-to-one relationships formed through the joins. Because we cannot see the tables and the data in them, we cannot tell you  exactly how to do that.

Comment: Hello everyone,
Thank you for your advice, I will rely on it to analyze, then solve my problem.